# How to ensure Ember Data remove the cache from store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've got a controller that shows the model count

```
const BlahController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    totalRows: Ember.computed('model.[]', function() {
        let items = this.get('model') || [];
        return items.get('length');
    }),
    ...
})
```

Then when I delete the model I do it using `destroyRecord` and even ensure that it's unloaded

```
model.destroyRecord().then(() => {
    this.get('store').unloadRecord(model);
}
```

Any idea why `totalRows` is never updated? I would've thought that by calling `store.unloadRecord` it will actually remove the model from the store and updates the model array in the controller?

The route hook model is something like this

```
const BlahRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('blah-model');
    },
})
```

Comment: show us route model hook method ? are u using findAll or query ?

Comment: I'm using `findAll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was using a mixin in my route, and within that mixin the `model` function actually created a new array using `this.store.peekAll().filter()` which obviously won't be updated as the array now points to another object /facepalm

Comment: Peekall has its own limitations compared to find